# Why I get garbage values when using 32-bit integer for storing data from fread()?

Tags: c

This is the code. I'm using 32-bit integer for buffer (storing data from fread()). After fread()-ing into `buffer`, I printed the values and found garbage values there. But when I used `unsigned char`, everything worked as expected, no garbage values. Why is it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

void print_array(int *array, int up_to);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover filename\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *inputfile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open specified file!\n");
        return 2;
    }
    FILE *outputfile = NULL;

    int *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
        return 4;
    }

    int file_count = 0;

    while (fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, inputfile) == BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        printf_array(buffer, 5);
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (outputfile != NULL)
                fclose(outputfile);

            // name the file
            char filename[8];
            sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", file_count);
            outputfile = fopen(filename, "a");
            file_count++;
        }

        if (outputfile != NULL)
            fwrite(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 1, outputfile);
    }

    fclose(inputfile);
    fclose(outputfile);
    free(buffer);
}

void print_array(int *array, int up_to)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < up_to; i++) 
        printf("element at index %i: %i\n", i, array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What makes you think they're garbage? What's actually in the file, and what is it printing?

Comment: BTW, why are you using `malloc()` for `buffer`? Just declare `int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]`.

Comment: In your `if` statement, `buffer[0]`, etc. are 32-bit integers, not bytes. But it looks like you might be trying to match a 4-byte magic number.

Comment: As an exercise, `#include <limits.h>` and use `unsigned buffer;`, Then following each `fread`, test `if (buffer < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < buffer) fprintf (stderr, "buffer (%u) would overflow int.\n", buffer);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `unsigned buffer;... buffer < INT_MIN` will convert `INT_MIN` to `unsigned`, making `buffer < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < buffer` always true.

Comment: Good point Eric. I guess `if ((long)buffer < (long)INT_MIN || ...` would be a better comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using *32-bit* `integer` for `buffer` (storing data from
>   fread())..., I printed the values and found garbage values there. But
>   when I used `unsigned char`, everything worked as expected, ... Why is
>   it?

It is unclear whether you were able to get an answer from the comments, but...

**Why is it?**

Much will depend on how the values are written to your `inputfile`. (are they written as `int` -- e.g. 4-bytes per value, or `unsigned char`, 1-byte per value?)

`int` and `unsigned char` are not interchangeable. You can read data in whatever sized chunks you like, using either `int` or `unsigned char`, but you can't have written data as `unsigned char` values, and expect to read the values back in as `int` -- you can't (unless you manually account for the type-size difference and `OR` and/or `shift` the needed bytes from each `int`).

In one case values were written in `1-byte` representations, in the other, values were written in `4-byte` representation. So you must properly size (or otherwise account for) the type of values originally *written* to the file.

*Why is it?* -- is a failure to match your read of the number of bytes as they were written. The type you choose for `buffer` effects *pointer arithmetic* and will result in differences in what is contained in `buffer[0], buffer[1], etc..` For example if you declare

```
char *buffer;      /* or just buffer[512] */
```

Then each index is `buffer` represents 1-byte of information. So if your file contains

```
ffd8ffea           /* 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xea */
```

Reading with `buffer` will result in `buffer[0] = 0xff, buffer[1] = 0xd8, etc...`. However, if you declare:

```
int *buffer;      /* or just buffer[512] */
```

Reading with `buffer` will result in `buffer[0] = 0xffd8ffea, buffer[1] = (next 4-bytes), etc..`. So depending on what is in your `inputfile`, your problem is here:

```
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && 
    buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
```

For you to read as `int` and still have the foregoing make sense, your file (endianess dependent) would have to contain bytes as follows,

```
ff000000d8000000ff000000ea000000   /* each value represented by 4-bytes */
```

So look at your `input` file with a hexdump or in a hex-editor to determine the layout of your `inputfile` and then match that to your `buffer` and `print_array` function -- which will suffer the same problems depending on the type of `array` there.